# Code First always wants to create new database when deploying to another PC

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, ef-code-first

i have a win-form app that uses CodeFirst to work with data.
after creating database from my models i have imported records to it from another database.
it works fine in my PC but when i deploy my app to another pc, codefirst tries to create new database and throws this error :

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot create file 
'E:\New folder (2)\Release\MyDB_log.ldf' because it already exists.
Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
Could not open new database 'MyDB'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
Cannot attach the file 'E:\New folder (2)\Release\MyDB.mdf' as database 'MyDB'.
```

connection string :

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppDbContext"
    connectionString="Server=.\sqlexpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

AppDbContext :

```
public class AppDbContext :DbContext 
{
    static AppDbContext() {
         Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(null);
    }
    public DbSet<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }


}
```

Migration class:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Sita_Election.DAL.AppDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        ContextKey = "Sita_Election.DAL.AppDbContext";
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Sita_Election.DAL.AppDbContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

so i want to use existing database that is created in development with codefirst,how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to have a database per application?

I would suggest using just a SQL DB if possible.

Thanks,

Phill

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is using a trusted connection so your IIS user is going to need access to that file or you could switch to a sql login. http://th2tran.blogspot.com/2009/06/underlying-provider-failed-on-open.html